# Error declaring a function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, declaration

This is a header file. But when I include it in the main.c it give me the next error: expected identifier or '(' before 'float'. I know it can be a very stupid error but i don't see it. The code is:

```
#ifndef Reference
#define Reference
float mat_a[3][3];
struct Reference_XS
{
int Bytes;
unsigned char *Buffer_Lectura;
};
struct Reference_XS Sist_Referecence(float q0,float q1,float q2,float q3,float val1,float val2,float val3)
{
float mat_a={(2*q0*q0)+(2*q1*q1)-1, (2*q1*q2)-(2*q0*q3), 2*q1*q3)+(2*q0*q1), (2*q1*q2)+(2*q0*q3), (2*q0*q0+(2*q2*q2)-1), (2*q2*q3)-(2*q0*q1), (2*q1*q3)-(2*q0*q2), (2*q2*q3)+(2*q0*q1), (2*q0*q0)+(2*q3*q3)-1};
float mat_b[3][1]={val1,val2,val3};
float mat_c[3][1];
int i,k;
float temp=0;
for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
{
    temp=0;
    for(k=0;k<3;k++) 
    {
        temp=mat_a[i][k]*mat_b[k][0]+temp;
        mat_c[i][0]=temp;       
    }
}
struct Reference_XS data={mat_c};
return data;
}
#endif
```

Comment: You mean to say, you have a function definition in a header file? I'm out.

Comment: I haven't used C for 15 years, but that didn't stop me from noticing that your code appears to have a `for` loop inside a `struct`.  Can this possibly not be an error?

Comment: The `mat_a` has mismatched parentheses. I recommend breaking it down and factoring terms, i.e. preprocess so writing it is not so difficult.

Comment: not only mismatched parantheses, `mat_a` isn't even an array

Comment: `struct Reference_XS data={mat_c};` is trying to initialize `data.Bytes` with a pointer to the first element of `mat_c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the initialization of your mat_a variable.

The first mistake is, that your float mat_a variable is initialized using the initializer list but you have to forgot to add the array idientifier after mat_a. What you should to is float mat_a[N] where N is the number of elements you float array contains.

The second error is a part of the statement where that an opening round bracket is missing. The bracket is missing after your second comma.

```
float mat_a={(2*q0*q0)+(2*q1*q1)-1, (2*q1*q2)-(2*q0*q3), (2*q1*q3)+(2*q0*q1), (2*q1*q2)+(2*q0*q3), (2*q0*q0+(2*q2*q2)-1), (2*q2*q3)-(2*q0*q1), (2*q1*q3)-(2*q0*q2), (2*q2*q3)+(2*q0*q1), (2*q0*q0)+(2*q3*q3)-1};
```

Comment: ... and it's a single float that can't be initialized by `{...}`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Have seen that right after posting the answer and have edited my answer to include both errors :)

Comment: @Ingo Leonhardt: Everything in C can be initialized by `{...}`. But supplying the right number of initializers between `{...}` is essential.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
float mat_a={(2*q0*q0)+(2*q1*q1)-1, (2*q1*q2)-(2*q0*q3), 2*q1*q3)+(2*q0*q1), (2*q1*q2)+(2*q0*q3), (2*q0*q0+(2*q2*q2)-1), (2*q2*q3)-(2*q0*q1), (2*q1*q3)-(2*q0*q2), (2*q2*q3)+(2*q0*q1), (2*q0*q0)+(2*q3*q3)-1};
```

you are trying to initialize a scalar object with multiple initializers and moreover the third initializer dors not have the open parenthesis

```
2*q1*q3)+(2*q0*q1),
```

^^^

It seems you wanted to define an array with the name mat_a   instead of the scalar object.